# how to know the view if we know the coordinates

Tags: android

i have a layout like this in my application

1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9

the user currently places cursor on some point on the screen, can i know to which view the pointer belongs to?? suppose if the user first touches 2 first then 2 down takes place. but when the user slides to 3 then it is  "2 move " event, but using event.getX() and event.getY() we can get the coordinates of the pointer. now how to get the current view having that coordinates(say 3).